# Nuxt auth returns me Bearer Bearer token

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, token, nuxt-auth

I am performing an authentication system with nuxtjs/auth, the main problem is that the token is sent from the back as follows: `Bearer token...`

When nuxtjs/auth processes it, it adds another Bearer to the beginning, being as follows: `Bearer Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzU...`

How can it be avoided?

Here I have my strategy:

```
  withoutotp: {
    _scheme: 'local',
    endpoints: {
      login: {
        url: '/users/v2/auth/bel',
        method: 'post',
        propertyName: 'response'
      },
      user: {
        url: '/users/v2/clients',
        method: 'get',
        propertyName: 'response'
      },
      logout: {
        url: '/users/v2/auth/logout',
        method: 'post'
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: No bro, I tried to create a configuration file to parse the token, but it doesn't overwrite the axios configuration when it is sent @kissu

Comment: Can you update your question with this configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

When you do have your string, use a `slice(7)` on it to remove the first Bearer.

Answer (score 0):

Just try setting `tokenType: false` in options. It worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).